# What does the length parameter in v8::Function::New?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

when creating a new function in v8, one can pass a length parameter ([docs](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.4/d5/d54/classv8_1_1_function.html#a83a8031c540b9946cc2d8fa5a3bd95f3)).
But I couldn't find out what it is good for as it does not seem to have any direct effect...

```
v8::Function::New(ctx, callback, data, length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript functions have a `length` property:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {}
var len = foo.length;  // 3
```

When you create a function on the C++ side, the `length` parameter to `v8::Function::New` (or `v8::FunctionTemplate::New`) allows you to specify the value of the resulting function's `length` property.